# Giving Value to Javascript using HiddenField

Tags: javascript, .net, vb.net

```
var json = {

            "id": "1", "name": "1", "data": "0,3048", "children": [{ "id": "11", "name": "11", "data": "0,3048", "children": [{ "id": "111", "name": "111", "data": "0,3048", "children": [] }, { "id": "112", "name": "112", "data": "0,3048", "children": [{ "id": "1121", "name": "1121", "data": "0,3048", "children": [] }, { "id": "1122", "name": "1122", "data": "0,3048", "children": []}]}] }, { "id": "12", "name": "12", "data": "0,3048", "children": [] }, { "id": "13", "name": "13", "data": "0,3048", "children": [{ "id": "131", "name": "131", "data": "0,3048", "children": [{ "id": "1311", "name": "1311", "data": "0,3048", "children": []}] }, { "id": "132", "name": "132", "data": "0,3048", "children": []}] }, { "id": "14", "name": "14", "data": "0,3048", "children": []}]
        };
```

How can i give these data to json using HiddenField ? My assunption was:

```
JSonID.Value = "{""id"":""1"",""name"":""1"",""data"":""0,3048"",""children"":[{""id"":""11"",""name"":""11"",""data"":""0,3048"",""children"":[{""id"":""111"",""name"":""111"",""data"":""0,3048"",""children"":[]},{""id"":""112"",""name"":""112"",""data"":""0,3048"",""children"":[{""id"":""1121"",""name"":""1121"",""data"":""0,3048"",""children"":[]},{""id"":""1122"",""name"":""1122"",""data"":""0,3048"",""children"":[]}]}]},{""id"":""12"",""name"":""12"",""data"":""0,3048"",""children"":[]},{""id"":""13"",""name"":""13"",""data"":""0,3048"",""children"":[{""id"":""131"",""name"":""131"",""data"":""0,3048"",""children"":[{""id"":""1311"",""name"":""1311"",""data"":""0,3048"",""children"":[]}]},{""id"":""132"",""name"":""132"",""data"":""0,3048"",""children"":[]}]},{""id"":""14"",""name"":""14"",""data"":""0,3048"",""children"":[]}]""}"
```

and `var json = document.getElementById('JSonID').value;`

it does not work . (JSonId.value is VB code so i used " as an escape character.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var json = document.getElementById('JSonID').value;
```

will simply assign the string held in the element to the `json` variable.  You need to parse it as an object:

```js
var json = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('JSonID').value);
```

`JSON.parse` is a native method in modern browsers, but if you need to support older ones, you can use [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works. i will accept this answer when accept time is over.

Comment: @user14570 Ok good.  If you're dealing with JSON in .Net a lot, you may want to take a look at [Json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/json)

Comment: Yeah i am beginner for json. I will check it out. thanks